# CRM 2011 Plug-in chaining

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online

Just a quick question I wasn't able to Google-fu about CRM 2011 plug-in behavior.  If I have a plug-in on, let's say Account, that updates another entity, let's say Contact, plug-ins registered on Contact messages will fire (correct?).

If those plug-ins are registered as synchronous will the Account plug-in have to wait for the Contact plug-ins to finish executing before it's execution is completed?  Does the chaining of the plug-ins create a blocking situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chris,

To your first question that plugins registered on Contact messages will fire? That is correct. and if you have selected synchronous that meaans:

The account plugin gets triggered makes some changes to the contact entity, and then the contact entity plugin makes some changes to contact entity. Only if the contact plugin finished without error then all the changes will apply, if not the contactplugin does a roll back aswell as the Account plugin. So no changes will be applied.

With Asynchronous it means that if the account plugin is finished, regardless if the contact plugin finishes without error, the changes apply to the contact entity.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What I'm really focused on learning is whether or not the synchronous execution of the Contact plugin creates a blocking scenario for the Account plugin.  Will the Account plugin not complete execution until after the Contact plugin completes?

Comment: @Chris, yes, you're correct. Control will not be passed back to the Account plugin until the synchronous plugin on the Contact has been completed.